# C++ bitmap to hold binary flags

Tags: c++, memory-management, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bitflags

the problem is this: I need to create a bitmap (a series of binary flags) to hold true/false information about a bunch of objects; the number of object is not known a priori so I have to allocate enough flags at runtime, possibly during the bitmap creation.

Given `max_num_elements` elements, my first idea was to allocate an array of `((num_elements/8)+1)*sizeof(char)` bits: since a `char` is 8bit long it can handle 8 binary flags, so I get the minimun number of `char`s to hold `num_elements` flags, with a max memory waste of 7bits.

The real problem is for checking/setting the flags: I tought to do some bitshifting on the whole array followed by a bitwise and to get flag n like

```
flag_n = (flag_array>>n)&0d1
```

but if I understood correctly, the shifting operation won't afffect the whole array, just the first element.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: unless I'm missing something, why not a long instead of a bitmap. The first bit holds true/false for some property, the second bit for another property and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is specialised to achieve exactly this.

[It is actually a problem in many cases](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill09.htm), since access to an element returns a proxy object rather than a `bool&`, so it doesn't quite behave like all the other containers, but it seems like in your case it suits what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much @bobtfish, didn't know about this specialization, it will be very helpful.
But reading the link i also found [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset), that fits best my needs, so I'll go for it in my project.